# determine what type of input field it is using jquery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to get all the inputs inside my form and fill the text fields with the value that came from the database. I would like to ask if there are other ways to do this because currently I am using nested switch case and it looks awful. So here is my code:

```
function filled(data){
    modal.find('.form-control, input').each(function(index, el) {
        var element = $(this).attr('name'),
                $this = $(this);

        switch($this.get(0).tagName){
            case "INPUT" :
                var $type = $this.attr('type');
                switch($type){
                    case "radio": case "checkbox":
                        if($this.prop('value') == data[element])
                            $this.prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                    case "text": case "number":
                        $this.val(data[element]);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "TEXTAREA" :
                $this.text(data[element]);
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `if...else..if` construct with `is()` like

```
function filled(data) {
  modal.find('.form-control, input').each(function(index, el) {
    var element = $(this).attr('name'),
      $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(':radio, :checkbox')) {
      //stuff
    } else if ($this.is(':text, [type="number"]')) {
      //stuff
    } else if ($this.is('textarea')) {
      //stuff
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: how can I determine which :radio should be checked? i have this code $this.prop('value') == data[element] to check if the value is the same..